# Excel conditional formating exact match on Characters

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, case-sensitive

I'm building a spread sheet and have been trying to get conditional formatting working how I would like. The cells will contain either one or two Characters and I have been trying to get it to fill the Cell with RED if it's say an uppercase 'W' or ORANGE if its a lower case 'w'. There will only be about 10 characters allowed (upper and lower W H F S O) but I also need say a GREEN for the two characters 'wh'.
So far the formatting gives me RED irrespective of it being a 'W' or 'w'. I've tried different combinations of tests and a lot of searching the internet, any assistance would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is case agnostic in Excel, i.e. `="W"="w"` evaluates to `TRUE`

You should use the `=code(text)` function to compare the ASCII codes of the cells in your conditional formatting formula

For instance `=code("W")` evaluates to ascii code 87 and `=code("w")` evaluates to ascii code 119

`=code(text)` only evaluates on the first character so you'll have to do something like `=and(code(left(cell, 1))=119, code(mid(cell, 2, 1))=104)` to capture the two character example "wh"

You may wind up with a lot of messy conditionals in the conditional formatting, so you could be better off doing all of that logic elsewhere in the spreadsheet

Comment: @Alan Woods did this answer your question?